# Need for basis for a topology

Tags: general-topology

Why did we need to define a basis for a topology?

I read that it is difficult to specify topology on a bigger set, so we define topology on a smaller collection.
Now I want to ask that what were the requirements to accomplish this plan?
When this question was in front of us, what actually we wanted to find?

Comment: Say I ask you what sets are open in usual topology on $\mathbb R$. Mind you, they can be pretty weird. You won't come up with any way of describing them all, except that possibly saying that they are, er, well... open. But a basis of open intervals is a totally different story. It is simple and easy to handle.

Comment: Isn't it quite natural to sometimes want to have a topology where some a priori arbitrary subsets shall be open? That amounts to considering the smallest (coarsest) topology where the given sets are open. We introduce the notion of subbasis of that topology for the given collection of sets and are unhappy because open sets are arbitrary unions of finite intersections of the given sets. Life would be nicer if we'd need one level less, i.e., only arbitrary unions of given sets. And the notion of basis is born.

Comment: For many things you'd want to do, such as proving a function is continuous or defining the product topology, the work is easier with a basis (you only have to check various things for basis elements, and these often carry additional structure that makes things easier to work with, such as open disks or open squares in the plane) or the simplest way to define a topology winds up being defining a certain basis for the topology (product topology, lower limit topology, etc.).

Comment: I’m interpreting your question as a historical one — when did the idea of a basis come about, what was the impetus for the idea, what problem were they working on, etc. — whereas others seem to have other interpretations. You may want to clarify your question.

Comment: A topology $T$ is _defined_ by the base $B$, on which you specify which subsets are open and which are not. Without it, your mathematical object is just a _set_, and you can not do analysis.

Comment: I don't understand the second paragraph of this question. What do you mean by "this plan" and "this question"?

Comment: @TannerSwett this plan- planning of defining topology on a smaller collection of sets

Comment: @TannerSwett yeah and this question - the question of how to define topology with less effort using smaller collection (the solution of the question turns out to use basis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There are various methods for constructing  (defining) topologies. Many "special" spaces have been very useful for some general theorems, as well as for producing examples and counter-examples for many conjectures. The Tychonoff product topology has been especially valuable. One widely used method to define a topology is to use a base.

   A collection $B$ of subsets of a set $X$ is a base for a topology on $X$ iff (i) $\cup B=X$ (i.e. every $p\in X$ belongs to at least one $b\in B$), and (ii) if $b_1,b_2\in B$ and $p\in b_1\cap b_2$ then there exists $b_3 \in B$ such that $p\in b_3\subset b_1\cap b_2.$

Note that if $b_1\cap b_2\in B$ whenever $b_1,b_2\in B$ then condition (ii) is satisfied by $b_3=b_1\cap b_2$. An example of a base not satisfying (ii), for the standard topology on $\Bbb R,$ is $$\{(x-r,x+s): x\in \Bbb R \land r,s>0 \land (\,[r\in \Bbb Q\land s \not \in \Bbb Q]\lor [r\not \in \Bbb Q\land s\in \Bbb Q]\,)\}.$$

2. Any topology is a base for itself but a smaller or simpler base may help to reveal much  about the space. Example: The standard topology  on $\Bbb R^n$ (for any $n\in \Bbb N$) is an uncountable set but it has a countable base. If a space $X$ has a countable base then (iii) $X$ has a countable dense subset , and (iv) if $F$ is a family of pair-wise disjoint open subsets of $X$ then $F$ is countable, and (v) $X$ is Lindelof, i.e. if $G$ is a family of open subsets of $X$ and $\cup G=X$ then there exists a countable $H\subset G$ such that $\cup H=X,$ and (vi) every subspace of $X$ also has a countable base.

Answer (score 2):

The biggest advantage to talking about bases is that they control the entirety of a space's topological information while being easy to work with. The prototypical example would be something like open balls or open rectangles in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be very strange, but open balls are simple to imagine and easy to work with. If I want to, say, prove that some function $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is continuous I would, in principal, need to prove that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open for every single open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. However, in actuality, what I will typically prove is that $f^{-1}(B_r(x))$ is open for all $x$ and for all sufficiently small $r$. This is sufficient though, because preimages are well behaved with unions, and because I can represent any arbitrary open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ as a union of open balls.

Comment: Also if $B$ is a  base for $X$ then $f$ is continuous iff the restriction $f|_b$ of $f$ to  the domain $b$ is continuous for each $b \in B.$.....+1